# multiple line and facet_grid in Bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 53 states and sex variable. e.g. the below DF is having 26 states.

```
set.seed(25)
test <- data.frame(
  state = sample(letters[1:26], 10000, replace = TRUE), 
  sex = sample(c("M","F"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Now I want to see which state has more female member, so I created a bar plot in a grid for each state and each grid has two bars (M,F).

```
test.pct = test %>% group_by(state, sex) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  mutate(pct=count/sum(count)) 

ggplot(test.pct, aes(x=sex, y=pct, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ state)
```

The problem is all these 26 grid are appearing in single line - visibility issue. I want to construct the plot in multiple frame, e.g 3X9 instead of 1X26.

Also the state should be ordered based of Female percentage.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1: Use `facet_wrap`. Problem #2: Reorder the state levels beforehand.

It could look like this:

```
ggplot(transform(test.pct, state=factor(state, 
                                        levels=with(subset(test.pct, sex=="F"), 
                                                    state[order(pct)]))), 
       aes(x=sex, y=pct, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ state, nrow = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part is straightforward: just use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`. The ordering is a bit trickier; you have to reorder the levels of the factor.  Just to make it a bit clearer, I've split the operation up into a few steps.  First, extract only female percentages, then find the order of those percentages, and finally use that order to rearrange the order of the levels of `state`.  That's a long-winded way of doing it, but I hope it makes the principle clear.

```
wom.pct <- test.pct %>% filter(sex == 'F')
ix <- order(wom.pct$pct)
test.pct$state <- factor(test.pct$state, levels = letters[1:26][ix])

ggplot(test.pct, aes(x=sex, y=pct, fill=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap( ~ state)
```